# Is it possible to access spent transaction output of a PKH with Plutus?

Tags: plutus

As stated in the title, I would like to be able to acess the already spent Tx Outputs of a particular Public Key.

How might one go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plutus newbie here. From my understanding, you need to hash PubKey to receive PubKeyHash, then construct an Address from PubKeyHash, and then use `utxoAt` function.

Answer (score 1):

When you say access, do you want to consume it or simply view it? Consuming an already consumed UTxO is not allowed because that would enable double spending:) If you just want to view it I think Yanis had a sufficient answer.